# Bet practice Initialize Pubnub in Node js

Tags: node.js, pubnub

I use pubnub on node js. I noticed that in my socket code i was constantly requiring pubnub.js and passing the pubsub keys every time i send a message (in my publish function below) . I have updated the code so that i create one instance of pubnub in my module. BUT, i'm wondering if this is bullet proof and the right way to do it.

```
(function(root, factory) {


  /* CommonJS */
  if (typeof exports == 'object')  module.exports = factory()

  /* AMD module */
  else if (typeof define == 'function' && define.amd) define(factory)

  /* Browser global */
  else root.Socket = factory();

}
(this, function() {

    //
    //
    // Is it ok to strike up a once only instance of pubnub here
    // in Node, or should i being doing it every time i call my publish 
    // function? The below should be the right way to do it> Require
    // pubnub when the node instance starts, get an instance and use it
    // forever more.
    //
    //
    var Pubnub = require("./pubnub"),
        pubnub = Pubnub({
            publish_key: "pub-c-xx",
            subscribe_key: "sub-c-xxx"
        });




    function publish(channel, data, cb){
      //
      // 
      // We use the instance above, BUT is this OK.
      //
      pubnub.publish({                                    
        channel : channel,
        message : data,
        callback : function(ev){
         if (cb) return cb(ev);
        }
      });
    }     




    var exports = {
        publish: publish,
    };

return exports;

}));
```

Comment: Yes, but you are using v3 of the PubNub Node SDK. Please use latest 4x. https://www.pubnub.com/docs/nodejs-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk

Comment: Just out of point what is benefit of V4 - I know it users slightly different subscribe/pub code  (event listeners)

Comment: It's not EOL :)

Comment: For those that don't know Craig means that V4 is the new product and V3 is an old unsupported product - So the difference is V3 is an end-of-life product. We will add it on the map to switch over ;-)